# How to get a String representation of the type in a generic static method

Tags: java, generics

Given the following method in Java:

```
public static <U> void foo() {


}
```

Within this method, how would I get the `SimpleName` or `CanonicalName` of type U?

Comment: In Java, generic types are erased, and so `U` becomes `Object` at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The type is not available at runtime.  Generic type parameters undergo a process called [*type erasure*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) whereby the compiler erases the generic type as if it didn't exist, for backwards compatibility.

Comment: All good responses, giving the credit to Mark for hitting it first, thanks Oscar for the alternative, and Ted for the most concise.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the class as a parameter:

```
public static <T> void foo(Class<T> klass) {
    System.out.println(klass.getCanonicalName());
    System.out.println(klass.getSimpleName());
}
```

There's no other way, because of Java generic's erasure, you don't have runtime access to the parameterized type information.

Comment: I'm aware of that option, I was hoping to avoid the extra param.

Answer (score 1):

Not, unless you pass the class as well

```
public static <U> void foo(Class<U> clazz ){
  System.out.println( clazz.toString() );
}
```

The reason for this is that the generics are erased during compilation, hence you cannot use them at runtime. See [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for more information about Type Erasure

Answer (score 1):

Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you can't. To quote the tutorial:

> When a generic type is instantiated, the compiler translates those types by a technique called *type erasure* — a process where the compiler removes all information related to type parameters and type arguments within a class or method. Type erasure enables Java applications that use generics to maintain binary compatibility with Java libraries and applications that were created before generics.